# A surjective functor between two distincts categories.

Tags: category-theory

Let $ \mathcal{C} $ and $ \mathcal{D} $ be two distinct categories.

I would like to know if there exists in category-theory, a notion of surjection $ F $, between $ \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{C} ) $ and $ \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{D} ) $ : $ F : \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{C} ) \to \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{D} ) $ ?

If the answer is yes, does, $ F : \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{C} ) \to \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{D} ) $ is surjective, mean that there exists a functor $ G : \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{D} ) \to \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{C} ) $ such that : $ F \circ G \simeq \mathrm{id} $ ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is $F$ intended to be a functor here? There is a standard definition of an essentially suerjective (or dense) functor that you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories. If you are talking about functors throughout, then your $G$ need not exist.

Comment: The literal phrasing of your question just asks whether there's a notion of surjection between two sets and whether surjections of sets always have right inverses, which is true but has nothing to do with categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the condition that a functor is surjective on objects is [evil](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence); it is not invariant under equivalences of categories. The "non-evil" version of surjectivity is [essential surjectivity](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+surjective+functor), and is equivalent to $F$ being surjective on isomorphism classes of objects.

This is far from enough to guarantee that $F$ has a right inverse; another necessary condition is that $F$ also has to be surjective on morphisms (which is not an evil condition), or [full](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+functor).

Comment: That's the right answer to the question the OP probably meant to ask. It's a shame that the OP did not act on my encouragement to fix the question (which is still phrased in terms of functions on objects).